# How to display duplicate values and unique values in two different tables Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

now  I'll try describe my situation correctly:
I have 2 models with same properties here is this models:

```
[Table("OperatorA")]
public class OperatorA
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string CallTime { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
[Table("OperatorB")]
public class OperatorB
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string CallTime { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
}
```

After that I have inserted data in  this tables and everything works fine, but -
now I need compare this two tables:
1. Check duplicate `Number` property in both table and view theme.
and 
2. View all `Number` values that is not duplicate.
Can  anyone help me with controller.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var operatorA = await db.OperatorAs.ToListAsync();
        var operatorB = await db.OperatorBs.ToListAsync();

        // Want get all operatorB Numbers witch not equals OperatorA Numbers
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that a query like this can easily cause big performance problems, depending of the number of records in the lists. Getting the whole lists to your application server with `await` and `ToListAsync` and later filtering the results in your controller is usually not a good practice. Use it only if you are sure that your lists will not get longer than a few hundreds of records (as a raw estimation). Do some metrics of execution times and amount of data used by the operation.

The best solution would be to do the query filtering in the database server, with the joins and filters applied **before** doing the `.ToList()`, because when you materialize the resulting list of records the query is executed in the database, and any further filtering or processing would not be done in the database but in the application server.

This example query that uses a `join` between the two tables would get you the list of `OperatorA` elements with `Number` repeated in `OperatorB`:

```
var query = db.OperatorAs
    .Join<OperatorA, OperatorB, string, OperatorA>(
        db.OperatorBs,
        a => a.Number,
        b => b.Number,
        (a, b) => a)
   .ToList();
```

It generates this SQL:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Number] AS [Number], 
    [Extent1].[CallTime] AS [CallTime], 
    [Extent1].[Duration] AS [Duration], 
    [Extent1].[Cost] AS [Cost]
    FROM  [dbo].[OperatorAs] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[OperatorBs] AS [Extent2] 
        ON ([Extent1].[Number] = [Extent2].[Number]) 
        OR (([Extent1].[Number] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[Number] IS NULL))
```

If the lists are really big you can also cause performance problems even in the  database server, but database servers are better prepared to deal with these issues than application servers. There are ways to fix it as well.